# Show that the function is a solution of Laplace's equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, orthogonality, laplacian

I am currently learning about general orthogonal coordinates. I was given this question to solve:

---

Consider the coordinate system  $(u, v, w)$  which are defined as followed:

$$x = (uv)^\frac{1}{2}cos(w)$$
$$y = (uv)^\frac{1}{2}sin(w)$$
$$z = \frac{1}{2}(u-v)$$

Show that if $F_n(x)$ satisfies the equation

$$x\frac{d^2F_n}{dx^2}+\frac{dF_n}{dx}+(v-\frac{m^2}{4x})F_n = 0$$

then $F_n(u)F_{-n}(v)e^{\pm imw}$ solution of Laplace's equation.

---

I am uncertain how to approach this question. Any thoughts or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Please let me if you need further information; I have already proven that the coordinates are orthogonal and written in the form of Laplace's equation.

P.S. Sorry, if I have used the inappropriate tags for this question.

Comment: Basically, you're asked to show that $\Phi(u,v,w):=F_n(u)F_{-n}(v)e^{\pm imw}$ is a solution to Laplace's equation (ie, $\nabla^2\Phi=0$, ie,$\Phi$ is harmonic). Calculate the second order partial derivatives $\Phi_{uu},\Phi_{vv},\Phi_{ww}$ using chain rule, sum them up and show it is $0$ using the given equation that $F_n$ satisfies.

Comment: You'll have to do it twice, once with $\Phi^+(u,v,w):=F_n(u)F_{-n}(v)e^{imw}$ and again with $\Phi^-(u,v,w):=F_n(u)F_{-n}(v)e^{-imw}$ and show that both $\nabla^2\Phi^+=0=\nabla^2\Phi^-$ using the given conditions.